# Restricting Internet access for Windows users using Ubuntu Server + Webmin

Tags: ubuntu, webfilter, content-filter

I want to restrict the Internet usage for a couple of Windows users on a network. The Server is a Ubuntu 10.04 Server running Webmin - all Windows users are setup as users on the Ubuntu server to authenticate to the Samba shares.

What I'd like to do is setup a proxy server on the Server that all users are routed through, and a few specific users would be restricted to access only a whitelist of websites, perhaps at specific times of the day.

What's a good way to achieve this using Ubuntu and Webmin?

Cheers,
   Matt

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound rude, but avoid Webmin. Only if you intend NOT to learn something, you should use Webmin.

So all your requirements can easily be done with Squid

- User/pw authentication and white list: http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/3871
- Time-based access: [http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch32_:_Controlling_Web_Access_with_Squid#Restricting_Web_Access_By_Time)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about webmin, but I am pretty sure that [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) can do what you want.